# Error with MongoDB and Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am working on MongoDB and Spring Data and following error is occuring when i just run my main class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;
```

Following libraries used:

```
1. spring-core 4.1.6.RELEASE
2. spring-data-mongodb 1.0.0.RELEASE
3. mongo-java-driver  3.2.2
4. spring-context   4.1.6.RELEASE
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to a newer version of spring-data-mongodb. Yours is really old. Check : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent

Comment: Thanks @LouisF. ..But facing this problem after correcting the previous one. Following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Data releases always depend on a minimum version of the core Spring Framework. Please make sure you use the required combinations of springframework, spring-data-commons and the individual module eg. spring-data-mongodb. 
In doubt have a look at the [spring-data wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki).

Here's a list of the baselines so far:

```
Hopper    - Spring 4.2 <- current release train
Gosling   - Spring 4.1
Fowler    - Spring 4.0
Evans     - Spring 4.0
Dijkstra  - Spring 3.2
```